# How to show modal on clicking bar in amcharts?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, amcharts4

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 400px;">
    <div class="modal fade" id="pieModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Pie Modal</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"
                                (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
                </div> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is my HTML code. I want to call `pieModal` when I'll click on any bar of the bar chart graph?
And below given is "component.ts" code. How I can call `pieModal` in this event function?

```
 series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function (ev) {
    var i = ev.target.dataItem.index;
    var temp=chart.data[i].userId;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is complex but here we go, 
(I don't know why my last post was deleted)

First of all, I recommend that "Pie modal" be another component and not within your base component,

something like this:

```
-chart
   -chart.component.ts
   -chart.component.html
   -chart.component.css
-modal
   -pieModal.component.ts
   -pieModal.component.html
   -pieModal.component.css
```

now chart.component.html maybe be like:

```
<p>Chart</p>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

and pieModal.component.html is the modal window body

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="pieModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Pie Modal</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"
                                (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
                </div> -->
    </div>
```

after that i used '@angular/material';  here is the page for reference https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview.

and must be declare in chart.component.ts like and atribute.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// for pie modal
import { MatDialog} from '@angular/material';

// for amchart 4 chart
import * as am4core from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core';
import * as am4charts from '@amcharts/amcharts4/charts';
import am4themes_animated from '@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated';
import am4themes_kelly from '@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/kelly';

// pie Modal
import { pieModalComponent } from '../../modal/pieModal.component';

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_kelly);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class chartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildchart();
  }

  buildChart() {
        // Create chart instance
    let chart = am4core.create('chartdiv', am4charts.XYChart3D);
  ... //  build your chart structure continue ....
  }
  
}
```

similarly, pieModal.component must have the following structure

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

// this interface is used to share data from chart.component to pieModal.component
export interface DialogData {
  grup: string;
  from: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pieModal',
  templateUrl: './pieModal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pieModal.component.css']
})
export class PieModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PieModalComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {
              }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

also, following the angular material reference, you must make sure that your app.modute.ts has the following structure.

```js
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChartComponent,
    PieModalComponent
    // ...
  ],
  exports:[
    MatDialogModule
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    //  IMPORTANT !!!!!!!!!!
    PieModalComponent
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
   // ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and finally, again in chart.component.ts, when creating the series of the graph. it is necessary that you pass as a parameter the "this.dialog" that is property of the ChartComponent class

```js
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildChart();
  }

buildChart() {
// ...
let testData = [{
      user: 'User name',
      groupType1: 230,
      groupType2: 42,
      groupType3: 75,
      groupType4: 342
}];
// Create chart instance
    let chart = am4core.create('chartdiv', am4charts.XYChart3D);
    
    chart.data = testData;
// ...


// Create series
    function createSeries(field: string, name: string, stacked: boolean, dialog: MatDialog) {
      let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries3D());
      series.dataFields.valueX = field;
      series.dataFields.categoryY = 'user';

      series.name = name;
      series.stacked = stacked;
      series.columns.template.tooltipText = '{name}: [bold]{valueX}[/][bold]';
      series.columns.template.fillOpacity = 1;
      series.columns.template.column3D.stroke = am4core.color('#fff');
      series.columns.template.column3D.strokeOpacity = 0.1;

      // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
      series.columns.template.events.on('hit', function(ev): void {
        // here the modal window is created and a value of chart.component is passed as parameter to pieModal.component
        const dialogRef = dialog.open(PieModalComponent, {
          width: '400px',
          height: '300px',
          data: {
            grup: ev.target.dataItem.categories.categoryY,
            from: 'from test'
          }
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log('The dialog was closed');
        });
      }, this);
     
     // ...
    } // end createSeries function
    
    //This function creates the series for each element of the data, and also passes this.dialog as a parameter.
    //
    testData.forEach((serie) => {
      if ( serie !== 'user') {
        createSeries(serie, serie , true, this.dialog);
      }
    });
```

and thats all, 
I sincerely wish I had been clear.